# How to get the same initial results if seed is provided , without restarting the Ipython kernel in Tensorflow

Tags: ipython, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am not sure , whether this question follow any logic as per the design of Tensorflow . Here is the Code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


np.random.seed(0)
tf.set_random_seed(0)

class Sample():


def __init__(self, hidden_dim = 50 , input_dim = 784):

    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.input_dim])
    self._create_network()
    self.__minimize()
    self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    self.sess.run(init)

def _create_network(self):

    self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim]))
    self.W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hidden_dim, self.input_dim]))

def __minimize(self):

    h1 = tf.matmul(self.x , self.W1)
    h2 = tf.matmul(h1, self.W2)
    reconstruction = tf.nn.sigmoid(h2)
    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.x , reconstruction))
    self.optimizer = \
        tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(self.loss)

def partial_fit(self, X):

    cost , _ = self.sess.run([self.loss, self.optimizer] , feed_dict = {self.x: X})
    return cost

import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
n_samples = mnist.train.num_examples
ex_1 = mnist.train.next_batch(1)[0]

model = Sample()
for i in xrange(11):
    c = model.partial_fit(ex_1)
    print c
```

The result is as follows :

0.498799
0.469001
0.449659
0.436665
0.424995
0.414473
0.404129
0.394458
0.39165
0.38483
0.380042

This result is achieved with seed 0 and it is same when I restart the kernel . But suppose , if I ran 10 iteration and then , if I have to start it from the scratch , how will i do it in Ipython . Because , if run after 10 or so iterations , the model continues to start from the remaining values .
I used tf.reset_default_graph() , but that has not make any change to the behavior .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `InterativeSession` but use a normal `Session`.

Create a new Session each time with the same seed and you will get the same results.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    model = Sample()
with Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    np.random.seed(0)
    tf.set_random_seed(0)
    for i in xrange(11):
        c = model.partial_fit(ex_1)
        print c
```

Comment: I was not asking about saving variables . What I was asking , how could I get the same results of first 10 iterations in the Ipython shell , without restarting the kernel , If i run 10 iterations in first cell and then run the 11 th iteration in next cell , the model resumes from where it was in the 10th iteration . But , if in the next cell , if i want the model to start from the same initial state , how could I do that without restarting the kernel .

Comment: Thanks for the help . But , as I run the sample code provided by you , each time I am executing the cell , the values seems different . Can you please have a check .

Comment: Yeah I think so .